# Equal space between log2 ticks on x-axis

Tags: plotting, scaling, around

I have the following set of data:

```
data = {{4, 2, 0.0001}, {8, 3, 0.0001}, {16, 8, 0.0001}, {31, 18, 4}, {63, 31, 8}, {125, 53, 3}, {250, 75, 4}, {500, 88, 2}};
```

(The first two numbers in each bracket are the coordinates of the point and the third one is the corresponding standard deviation.)

I'd like to plot this data as follows:

```
data0 = {#, Around[##2]} & @@@ data;
ListPlot[data0, IntervalMarkers -> "Bars", PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> {{4, 8, 16, 31, 63, 125, 250, 500}, {0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

which results in:

[image]

I have two questions:

**1.** How can I make the intervals between the almost `Log2` separated ticks on the $x$-axis even and equally spaced? A sample output is shown in the figure below.

[image]

**2.** When I use `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot`, the points disappear. How can I keep the markers for data points while using this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = ListPlot[data0, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
  Ticks -> {data[[All, 1]], Range[0, 100, 20]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}];
    
p2 = ListLinePlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
  Ticks -> {data[[All, 1]], Range[0, 100, 20]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64. Cannot say what the problem could be. Please wait so that someone else can make an improvement to this answer or confirm this behavior on 13.1.

Comment: @Marteen, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Since this behavior has not changed on my system, I am afraid, I can't say, why that would be. Perhaps you can investigate this behavior and reduce it to the simplest form and start a fresh post.

Comment: @Marteen, you can post a new question on this site and I am sure someone will help you with interpolation.